# user defined command should be sourced every time at startup - neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm using Neovim and have the following line in my .init.vim:

```
command! FZF FloatermNew fzf
```

It only takes effect if I source $MYVIMRC file every time at startup with `:so $MYVIMRC` command otherwise it doesn't work.

.init.vim

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
" Plugins will go here in the middle."
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'voldikss/vim-floaterm'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'arcticicestudio/nord-vim'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
Plug 'fatih/vim-go'
"Plug 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe', { 'do': './install.py --clangd-completer' }
Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plug 'sonph/onehalf', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
call plug#end()



source $HOME/.config/nvim/plug-config/floaterm.vim

command! FZF FloatermNew fzf





" now commands are not case-sensitive and write them and hit the tab for
" completion 
set ignorecase

"theme
colorscheme nord
set termguicolors
let g:lightline = {'colorscheme': 'deus'}
syntax on

if !exists("g:syntax_on")
    syntax enable
endif

" Plugins settings
let g:go_fmt_command = "goimports"
let g:go_list_type = "quickfix"
"Golang
let g:go_auto_type_info = 1
let g:go_gocode_unimported_packages = 1
set updatetime=100

let g:go_gopls_complete_unimported = 1


"set completeopt-=preview
"let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion = 1

" ######### Coc Configs #########


" ######### Airline Configs #########
let g:airline_theme='deus'
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#left_sep = ' '
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#left_alt_sep = '|'

" ######### FZF Configs #########



"line number
set number

"Auto-save before make command
set autowrite


"Custom key maps
map <F4> :w<CR>:!make<CR>
"without defining run target in Makefile
"map <F4> :w<CR>:!make && make run<CR>





"How can I open a NERDTree automatically when vim starts up?
"autocmd vimenter * NERDTree

"How can I close vim if the only window left open is a NERDTree?
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif

"focus on right window instead of nerdtree
au VimEnter * wincmd l



map <C-f> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>

"remove tilde for empty lines.
set fcs=eob:\ 

set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set noexpandtab

"show a vertical line in the right side of page to indicate a limit for total characters in a line.
"set colorcolumn=110
"highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=darkgray

"Auto-completion
"let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/Users/admin/.config/nvim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
"to improve source code navigation, add something like this to your nvim configuration:
"au FileType c,cpp nnoremap <buffer> <c-]> :YcmCompleter GoTo<CR>

"let g:ycm_server_keep_logfiles = 1
"let g:ycm_server_log_level = 'debug'

Thanks in advance!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something called in vim `after-directory` which is helpful for this situation where you put .vim files and pass the path to `:runtimepath` command.
I'm using neovim so after-directory in my workflow in a macOS system is like below:

`~/.config/nvim/after/plugin/commands.vim`
so I `command! FZF FloatermNew fzf` in that file and then give file path to the `:runtimepath` so this file will be sourced after all other `:scriptnames` files sourced.